# Alternator's saturation in load and no-load conditions

Tags: generator, saturation, alternator

When a ferromagnetic material is exposed to a magnetic field in which it moves, some voltage is induced in the material. If you increase the magnetic field, the voltage is increased up to a point, and this point is called saturation. I know saturation depends on its charactaristic.

Is it valid for alternators as well? How does load or current impact the saturation voltage in alternators?

Comment: It's the same: instantaneous value of current produces an instantaneous value of magnetic field for either AC or DC (ignoring frequency or time response) and that value determines the number of flux lines and whether the core is saturated at that instant. I've not heard of the concept of voltage in the core though. Maybe you can model it that way like eddy currents but seems like it would be just as difficult to measure.

Comment: @DKNguyen so what do you think about load ? Can load impact saturation point ?

Comment: Load is no different from current. They are the same thing. I am not sure why you are talking about them as if they are different.

Comment: According to your knowledges, the more load the more saturation voltage, but in my lesson, we experiemented inverse.

Comment: Your terms are all mixed up. You never used the term saturation voltage up until now. Increased saturation means decreased voltage. Saturation is a state and *is not* the same as voltage when saturated.

Comment: Sorry for that, sometimes we assume another peoples thik as us mistakely.

Comment: It sounds more like language differences than technical issues.

Comment: Also, voltage output is the same as coil voltage, which is different from voltage in the core I mentioned earlier when I said I had never heard of that before. When you say "voltage in the material" it sounds like you mean a voltage in the core itself, not the coil around the core.

Answer (score 1):

Saturation can occur whenever there is a magnetic material in the magnetic path.

There are two types of alternator, permanent magnet, and wound magnet.

A permanent magnet one, by design, won't have the core materials up to a saturation field level.

Theoretically, if you run a wound rotor alternator at a high enough current, you can saturate the iron path. In practice, the air gap between rotor and stator means that a relatively large current is needed to get the field up to saturation, and it may not be possible to reach that current because of heating in the windings.

Comment: What about load ? How does load impact saturation in alternators ? Acording to my assignment, the more load the less saturation point, but I don't understand how load impact it.

Comment: @Wtow What exactly do you mean by "more load"? Because it doesn't sound like you mean what everyone else means when they say that.

Comment: In our laboratory lesson, we made an experiement. In this experiement, we tried to produce AC voltage by DC synchron motor and generator. We fulled speed of the motor and exposed some  excitation voltage with resistor load at generator and without load. We saw when there is no load, alternator saturate at bigger excitation voltage, but how ?

Comment: @Wtow Be careful about terms here, the term "excitation voltage" does not mean the output voltage of the generator. It means the voltage applied to the field coils of the generator.

Comment: @DKNguyen yes but it happened, excitation voltage  and output were also decreased. How to resistance impact both ?

Comment: @Wtow Oh, so you really are referring to both output and excitation voltage? Decreased resistance = more output current and that output current on the output winding can also induce backwards onto the field winding to reduce the field excitation voltage. Induction can happen both ways, I think it's called "armature reaction".

Comment: @DKNguyen Thanks for everything, I am trying to understand but can't. If you have something to make it easy, please share with me. Otherwise I will make another research with your knowledges.

Comment: @DKNguyen, I made some research, if I am not wrong, saturation excitation voltage point is not changed by load but alternator output can be changed because of the current ? Can you approve me ?

Comment: @Wtow The load is what is connected to the output of the alternator. The current produced by the alternator is the load current or output current. So I do not know what you mean when you say it can be changed by one but not the other.

Answer (score 0):

There is alot of confusion due to lack of clear terms being use to commnuncate, as DKN tries to correct.
Generator excitation comes from a magnetic field on the rotor. In permanent magnet generator the field comes from the magnets.  In a wound field generator the field comes from current in the field windings. The field goes across the air gap to the stator backiron and windings to induce output voltage. Connect a load and current will flow in the output.  Increase the field current, induced output voltage goes up. Increase load (lower load resistance) and output current increases, and a small droop in output voltage results. The field can be raised a little to increase output voltage.  If tge field is raised too much, backiron saturates and voltage goes no higher.